# 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, json

soy nuevo y tengo un error en la plataforma que estoy programando con php,me aparece actualmente este error, ya le coloque los permisos a las carpetas y a los archivos, en mi localhost funciona perfecto el error esta en el servidor que es con IIS8
--
 POST http://*******/Controller/Login/Login.php 500 (Internal Server Error)  jquery-3.3.1.js:9600.
se que la funcion de ajax esta funcionando bien por que me arroja el mensaje de error que le coloque
así se ve el error en la consola de chrome
[image: 1]]

es un formulario que envia 2 campos el post,
aca mi codigo

asi se ve el error en el network de chrome
[image: 2]]
**funcion de ajax**

```js
//---------------- FUNCION AJAX ------------------//
    function fajax(url, parametros, metodo) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: parametros,
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(document).ajaxStop();
                $(document).ajaxStart();
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;',
            timeout: 8000,
            success: function (datos) {
                metodo(datos);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("Por favor, valida tu conexión !")
            }
        })
    }
```

**funcion del login**

```js
//-------------- LOGIN ------------------------//
    var url = "index.php";
    var parametros = "acceso=true";
    var metodo = function (datos) {
        $("#login").validate({
            rules: {
                correo: {required: true, email: true},
                contrasena: {required: true, minlength: 3}
            },
            messages: {
                correo: {
                    required: '<font color="red"> Debe colocar elcorreo</font>',
                    email: '<font color="red">Debe colocar su correo electronico</font>',
                },
                contrasena: {
                    required: "Debe colocar una contraseña",
                    minlength: '<font color="red">Debe colocar minimo 3 cracteres</font>',

                },
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                var url = "Controller/Login/Login.php";
                var parametros = $("#login").serialize();
                var metodo = function (datos) {
                  
                    datos = $.parseJSON(datos);
                    if (datos.success == "ok") {
                        if (datos["result"][0]["lenguaje"] == 'SPANISH') {
                            // alerPos("Perfecto !", "<b>" + datos["result"][0]["NombreColabora"] + " " + datos["result"][0]["ApellidoColabora"] + " Bienvenido</b>");
                            setTimeout("location.href='Pages/Main.php'", 1000);
                        } else {
                            // alerPos("Excellent !", "<b>" + datos["result"][0]["NombreColabora"] + " " + datos["result"][0]["ApellidoColabora"] + " Welcome</b>");
                            setTimeout("location.href='EN/Pages/Main.php'", 1000);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alerNeg("Error ", "<br>error, it is not possible to enter.<br>");
                    }
                };
                fajax(url, parametros, metodo);
            }
        });
    };
    fajax(url, parametros, metodo);
```

**Controller**

```html
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    //session_name("seExtra");
    require '../../CLASS/BD/datos.php';
    require '../../CLASS/BD/MySQLi.php';
    require '../../CLASS/VO/ColaboradorVO.php';
    require '../../CLASS/DAO/loginDAO.php';
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $ColaboraVO = new LoginDAO();
    $data = json_encode($_POST);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $ColaboraVO->Login($json);
} else { header("location:../.././");}
```

**espero me puedan colaborar pronto, agradezco su ayuda de ante mano**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude solucionar el problema, publico la solución.

resulta que manejaba la conexión a la BDD separando los datos en un archivo y la conexión en otro, la solución fue, colocar los datos directos en el archivo de conexión y quitar de todos los archivos la importación del archivo de datos de conexión, esto me paso un servidor con windows server 2012 R2 y IIS 8.

 publico los códigos para hacer mas entendible la solución.

**Archivo de datos de conexión a la BDD**

```html
<?php
class Datos {
    private $hostname = 'UBICACION DE LA BDD';
    private $usuario = 'USUARIO DE LA BDD'
    private $clave = 'CLAVE DE CONEXION';
    private $db = 'NOMBRE DE LA BDD';
    
    public function Datos() {
        
    }
    public function get_hostname() {
        return $this->hostname;
    }
    public function get_usuario() {
        return $this->usuario;
    }
    public function get_clave() {
        return $this->clave;
    }
    public function get_DB() {
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```html
<?php
if ($_POST) {
 //   ob_start();
    session_start();
    //session_name("seExtra");
 //   include '../CLASS/BD/datos.php';
    require '../../CLASS/BD/MySQLi.php';
    require '../../CLASS/VO/ColaboradorVO.php';
    require '../../CLASS/DAO/loginDAO.php';
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    $ColaboraVO = new LoginDAO();
    $data = json_encode($_POST);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $ColaboraVO->Login($json);
 } else { header("location:../.././");} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los errores 500 son por parte del servidor. Lo que quiere decir que dentro de tu archivo php alguna de tus funciones no esta realizando su deber por lo que truena en ese momento.

Me causa ruido esta sección.

```
header("location:../.././");
```

Ya que si no mal recuerdo esto hace la redirección a la carpeta, sin embargo si la carpeta no contiene un archivo index.php entonces no estas referenciando a nada. Por lo que podrias empezar por ahi para ver si la redirección esta bien hecha.

Ademas si traducimos tu redireccion seria "Sube una carpeta, sube otra carpeta, en esta carpeta esta...." seguro que no seria "location:../../index.php" o "location: ../../../index.php"

Comment: hola  @Cezar-Gutz, gracias por tu comentario, la plataforma funciona perfecto en el localhost, el header("location:../.././"); del if lo que hace es llevarme a la raíz así entra al index.php

Comment: buenos dias, los errores 500 se deber a la incompatibilidad de las funciones php que realizar según la versión php que tiene en le servidor y en local no es la misma

Comment: hola @marcosalbertosaavedrasanabr la version de php es la misma

Comment: hola @Fly, yo edite la imagen para que no apareciera la url del sitio, al igual si miras en la imagen de color rosa, sin embargo la url del sitio esta bien, tambien esta bien la url de direccionamento dentro de la funcion de logueo